# Apple Mach-O linker Error clang: error: no such file or directory libcocos2dx.a

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocos2d-x

Using cocos2d-x in mac, I have been getting this error from a long time and i used to bypass this by copying libcocos2dx.a from another folder. 
But now its causing even more problem building app using provision profiles,as its unable to build.

I tried

-Clearing derived data and restarting xcode. 
-Build architecture i removed armv6 and i386 
-Build active architecture to "YES" 
-Searched lot of forums :(
-Using relative paths in search paths.

I can't fix this and cant move forward with anything.

Comment: Apparently the cocos2dx library target is not correctly setup or missing. Try setting up a new project, and once that works add your sources and resource files to the new project.

Comment: Hi, guessed you would answer as i saw you answer a lot of cocos2d questions in many forums :). Anyway is there a way how we can shift the target based cocos2d-x project(created by script) to directly add the cocos2d-x files like in a libs folder(which happens only when you create in xcode->create project)?.

Comment: no idea, i'm not an active cocos2dx user